# Error while running spring boot on external tomcat inside docker container

Tags: spring-boot, docker, tomcat

My spring-boot service(in a centos 7 server) runs ok on docker with embedded tomcat. But when I tried to deploy the .war file inside a docker container with a tomcat, it fails. I followed the steps described in the link: https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-with-external-tomcat

What might the problem and how to solve this?

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.myservice</groupId>
    <artifactId>myservice</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>myservice</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.12</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
            <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-zipkin</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.13</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- start of security dependencies -->

        <!-- end of security dependencies -->

    </dependencies>


    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <!-- <version>Camden.SR5</version> -->
                <version>Finchley.RELEASE</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM tomcat:8-jre8
ADD target/*.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/
CMD ["catalina.sh", "run"]
```

Docker Log:

```
2019-10-15 05:13:49.205  INFO [myservice,,,] 1 --- [ost-startStop-1] com.myservice.service.Application            : Started Application in 13.674 seconds (JVM running for 20.222)
15-Oct-2019 05:13:49.263 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
15-Oct-2019 05:13:49.295 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more Filters failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
15-Oct-2019 05:13:49.296 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [/myservice-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT] startup failed due to previous errors
```

Tomcat Log:

```
# cat localhost.2019-10-15.log
15-Oct-2019 05:13:35.357 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log 2 Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath
15-Oct-2019 05:13:42.403 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
15-Oct-2019 05:13:49.295 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart Exception starting filter [controllerMethodInterceptor]
        java.lang.AbstractMethodError
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:285)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:112)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4615)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5262)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:754)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:730)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:744)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:980)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1851)
                at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
15-Oct-2019 05:13:49.302 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
15-Oct-2019 05:13:50.086 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log ContextListener: contextInitialized()
15-Oct-2019 05:13:50.086 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log SessionListener: contextInitialized()
15-Oct-2019 05:13:50.088 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log ContextListener: attributeAdded('StockTicker', 'async.Stockticker@1e2bc9bf')
```

**Edit**
mvn dependency:tree

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING]
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.myservice:myservice:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'dependencyManagement.dependencies.dependency.exclusions.exclusion.artifactId' for org.quartz-scheduler:quartz:jar with value '*' does not match a valid id pattern. @ org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.1.6.RELEASE, /root/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-dependencies/2.1.6.RELEASE/spring-boot-dependencies-2.1.6.RELEASE.pom, line 2619, column 25
[WARNING] 'dependencyManagement.dependencies.dependency.exclusions.exclusion.artifactId' for com.netflix.eureka:eureka-core:jar with value '*' does not match a valid id pattern. @ org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-netflix-dependencies:2.0.0.RELEASE, /root/.m2/repository/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-netflix-dependencies/2.0.0.RELEASE/spring-cloud-netflix-dependencies-2.0.0.RELEASE.pom, line 251, column 19
[WARNING]
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING]
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING]
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building myservice 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:3.1.1:tree (default-cli) @ myservice ---
[INFO] com.myservice:myservice:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:2.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.1.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:2.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:2.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:jar:2.11.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.11.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.26:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:jar:1.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.1.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:5.1.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.23:runtime
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:2.1.6.RELEASE:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:9.0.21:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:9.0.21:provided
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:9.0.21:provided
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:2.1.6.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:2.1.6.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:jar:2.1.6.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.4.0:test
[INFO] |  |  \- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.3:test
[INFO] |  |     \- net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:1.2:test
[INFO] |  |        \- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:5.0.4:test
[INFO] |  +- junit:junit:jar:4.12:test
[INFO] |  +- org.assertj:assertj-core:jar:3.11.1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:2.23.4:test
[INFO] |  |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.9.13:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-agent:jar:1.9.13:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:2.6:test
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] |  +- org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:jar:1.5.0:test
[INFO] |  |  \- com.vaadin.external.google:android-json:jar:0.0.20131108.vaadin1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:5.1.8.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  \- org.xmlunit:xmlunit-core:jar:2.6.2:test
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:2.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json:jar:2.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:jar:2.9.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.9.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names:jar:2.9.9:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:jar:6.0.17.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:2.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.2.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:5.1.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.1.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:5.1.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:5.1.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:jar:2.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:jar:2.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.zaxxer:HikariCP:jar:3.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:5.1.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.transaction:javax.transaction-api:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- javax.activation:javax.activation-api:jar:1.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.3.10.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.persistence:javax.persistence-api:jar:2.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.23.2-GA:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss:jandex:jar:2.0.5.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.dom4j:dom4j:jar:2.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:5.0.4.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:2.1.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:2.1.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:5.1.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:5.1.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:5.1.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.projectlombok:lombok:jar:1.18.8:compile
[INFO] +- org.postgresql:postgresql:jar:42.2.5:runtime
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:jar:2.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:5.1.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.9.4:compile
[INFO] +- io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:jar:2.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.swagger:swagger-annotations:jar:1.5.20:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.swagger:swagger-models:jar:1.5.20:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.springfox:springfox-spi:jar:2.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- io.springfox:springfox-core:jar:2.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.springfox:springfox-schema:jar:2.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.springfox:springfox-swagger-common:jar:2.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.springfox:springfox-spring-web:jar:2.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:20.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.26:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.plugin:spring-plugin-core:jar:1.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.plugin:spring-plugin-metadata:jar:1.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.mapstruct:mapstruct:jar:1.2.0.Final:compile
[INFO] +- io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:jar:2.9.2:compile
[INFO] +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.12:compile
[INFO] +- org.modelmapper:modelmapper:jar:0.7.4:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.4:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-config-client:jar:2.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-commons:jar:2.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-crypto:jar:5.1.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-context:jar:2.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.9.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.9.9:compile
[INFO] |     \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.9.9:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client:jar:2.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter:jar:2.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-rsa:jar:1.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on:jar:1.56:compile
[INFO] |  |        \- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:jar:1.56:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-netflix-core:jar:2.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client:jar:2.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.netflix.eureka:eureka-client:jar:1.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.codehaus.jettison:jettison:jar:1.3.7:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  \- stax:stax-api:jar:1.0.1:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- com.netflix.netflix-commons:netflix-eventbus:jar:0.3.0:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.netflix.netflix-commons:netflix-infix:jar:0.3.0:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- commons-jxpath:commons-jxpath:jar:1.3:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.10.2:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.antlr:antlr-runtime:jar:3.4:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |  \- org.antlr:stringtemplate:jar:3.2.1:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.8.5:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.commons:commons-math:jar:2.2:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- com.netflix.archaius:archaius-core:jar:0.7.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.ws.rs:jsr311-api:jar:1.1.1:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- com.netflix.servo:servo-core:jar:0.12.21:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-core:jar:1.19.1:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-client:jar:1.19.1:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- com.sun.jersey.contribs:jersey-apache-client4:jar:1.19.1:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.9:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.11:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- com.google.inject:guice:jar:4.1.0:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  +- javax.inject:javax.inject:jar:1:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:runtime
[INFO] |  |  \- com.github.vlsi.compactmap:compactmap:jar:1.2.1:runtime
[INFO] |  |     \- com.github.andrewoma.dexx:dexx-collections:jar:0.2:runtime
[INFO] |  +- com.netflix.eureka:eureka-core:jar:1.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.codehaus.woodstox:woodstox-core-asl:jar:4.4.1:runtime
[INFO] |  |     +- javax.xml.stream:stax-api:jar:1.0-2:runtime
[INFO] |  |     \- org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:jar:3.1.4:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-archaius:jar:2.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-netflix-ribbon:jar:2.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-netflix-archaius:jar:2.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- commons-configuration:commons-configuration:jar:1.8:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-ribbon:jar:2.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.netflix.ribbon:ribbon:jar:2.2.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.netflix.ribbon:ribbon-transport:jar:2.2.5:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- io.reactivex:rxnetty-contexts:jar:0.4.9:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- io.reactivex:rxnetty-servo:jar:0.4.9:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.netflix.hystrix:hystrix-core:jar:1.5.12:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.hdrhistogram:HdrHistogram:jar:2.1.9:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  \- io.reactivex:rxnetty:jar:0.4.9:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |     +- io.netty:netty-codec-http:jar:4.1.36.Final:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |     |  +- io.netty:netty-common:jar:4.1.36.Final:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |     |  +- io.netty:netty-buffer:jar:4.1.36.Final:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |     |  +- io.netty:netty-transport:jar:4.1.36.Final:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |     |  |  \- io.netty:netty-resolver:jar:4.1.36.Final:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |     |  +- io.netty:netty-codec:jar:4.1.36.Final:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |     |  \- io.netty:netty-handler:jar:4.1.36.Final:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |     \- io.netty:netty-transport-native-epoll:jar:4.1.36.Final:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |        \- io.netty:netty-transport-native-unix-common:jar:4.1.36.Final:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- com.netflix.ribbon:ribbon-core:jar:2.2.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.netflix.ribbon:ribbon-httpclient:jar:2.2.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.2:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.netflix.netflix-commons:netflix-commons-util:jar:0.3.0:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- com.netflix.ribbon:ribbon-loadbalancer:jar:2.2.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.netflix.netflix-commons:netflix-statistics:jar:0.1.1:runtime
[INFO] |  |  \- io.reactivex:rxjava:jar:1.3.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.netflix.ribbon:ribbon-eureka:jar:2.2.5:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.thoughtworks.xstream:xstream:jar:1.4.10:compile
[INFO] |     +- xmlpull:xmlpull:jar:1.1.3.1:compile
[INFO] |     \- xpp3:xpp3_min:jar:1.1.4c:compile
[INFO] \- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile
[INFO]    \- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 5.395s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Oct 15 15:17:39 UTC 2019
[INFO] Final Memory: 25M/363M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: What does `mvn dependency:tree` output?

Comment: Edit the post and added the output of the command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are dependencies to apache-tomcat 9.0.21 in your project. This suggest that at least some modules depend on tomcat 9 directly or on servlet 4.0 specification.

Try to upgrade your docker image to Tomcat 9.